# How to debug Cassandra validation errors

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cql

I'm at the end of the reasonable rope trying to understand why some of my Cassandra queries won't work when invoked from NodeJS.

TL;DR - Is there a way to turn on debug on server-side reasoning why validation fails?

My specific headagainstwallbanging problem. Cassandra 2.2.4, drivers 2.2.2. Given the following table definition:

```
create table messages (id varchar,enterprise_id uuid,primary key(id, enterprise_id)
```

I pass in the following query:

```
cassandra.execute("select id from messages where id = ? and enterprise_id = ?",
  [local,domain],{},...);
```

local is of string type, domain is of `Uuid` type (returned by Cassandra from an earlier query). This produces error of *8704: String didn't validate.*. I've made sure to convert first arg to string, and second to either `Uuid` or string, the error doesn't change. I've printed out the object sent out by `Client._innerExecute`, and it looks OK:

```
cassandra request:{"streamId":null,"query":"select id from messages where id = ? and enterprise_id = ?",
"params":["fef86640-b0fb-11e5-8518-5b5a19241119","32d2a682-af07-4108-a15a-de6f8a75e811"],
"options":{"consistency":1,"fetchSize":5000,"prepare":false,"retryOnTimeout":true,
"prepared":true,"routingKey":null},"consistency":1,"hints":[]}
```

At the end, there is absolutely no output in the server's debug (or any other) log, indicating there was any kind of error. Considering it's hard to get J/S to print out object "types", it's unclear what is being sent, and what are the server's expectations.

Of course, running this directly in cqlsh works just fine:

```
cassandra@cqlsh:a> SELECT * from messages WHERE 
    ... id = '92ec8eb0-b0f9-11e5-8518-5b5a19241119' and
    ... enterprise_id = 32d2a682-af07-4108-a15a-de6f8a75e811 ;
 id | enterprise_id
----+---------------
(0 rows)
```

So, I'm looking for a way to just shed some light on what is going on with execution.

P.S. Incidentally, as I was meddling with Cassandra driver code, I realized I used `prepared` instead of `prepare`, making non-prepared queries. I don't know what the actual difference is, but once I made it prepared, things started to work in this particular case. But I still really really wanna find out how to debug these kind of issues shall I run into them again.

Answer (score 0):

The expected javascript type for a `uuid` parameter is a [`Uuid`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/nodejs/3.0/module-types-Uuid.html).

In your case, it should be:

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const query = 'select id from messages where id = ? and enterprise_id = ?';
client.execute(query, [ id, cassandra.types.Uuid.fromString(eid) ], callback);
```

Visit the [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.0/nodejs-driver/reference/uuids-timeuuids.html) or [Uuid API docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/nodejs/3.0/module-types-Uuid.html) for more information.

Comment: The suggested solution doesn't work (at least in my case), and I'm not as much asking for what code to put down to make it work, but how to debug what's going on, and your answer doesn't quite answer that.